# Take result of remote php execution and write it to variable in Java Script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a tool on remote host, that converts characters to numbers:

somehost.com/tool.php?a=test

How can I write result of it's execution to variable in my JS script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an Ajax query with Javascript, with XMLHttpRequest() :

```
var myToolResponse = null;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           myToolResponse = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
       else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400');
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
       }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://somehost.com/tool.php?a=test", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The `myToolResponse` variable will contain the response of your tool, after the load of your tool.php url.

If the `somehost` is not the same as the url of your javascript page, you have to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your tool.php script :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Arno. Yes, I've tried XMLHttpRequest(), but it returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I don't have access to tool.php
Is there any different way in this situation?
May be I can look inside tool.php to rewrite conversion algorithm by myself?

Comment: If you are able to rewrite the algorithm, you can convert it for javascript language. If you can not add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, you won't be able to call an Ajax request. Another idea could be to develop a proxy endpoint on your host (server-side) that will call the somehost.com, and the Ajax query will work with the same host.